# boost.asio with vfork

Tags: process, fork, boost-asio

As we know, when calling `fork()` together with boost.asio environment, we should call `notify_fork()` immediately before and after `fork()`. But how about `vfork()`? Should we call them in both parent and child process? I don't think so but in my machine, an unexpected (and random) behavior occurs but after calling them, it runs well.

PS: `vfork()` is followed by an `exec()` calling a brand new process immediately.

Please be free to point me out what's wrong.

Comment: IIRC a child process modifying any data after `vfork(2)` invokes undefined behavior. Can you elaborate on the behavior you encounter?